# How do I generate missing values of an array in Fortran?

Tags: fortran

I have an array, x, with dimension 4, that has the following values

```
3, 4.5, 7, 9
```

How do I generate the missing values, and make a new one like this?

```
3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5, ...,9
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are your rules for the missing values? Is the result always a product of a natural number and 0.5?

Comment: Why can't you just use `[(0.5*i, i=6, 18)]` ?

Comment: I have no rules, i can choose the dimension of the step.

Comment: so I should do something like `step = 0.5` and `do i=1,4
  xnew(i) = x(1) + step*i`?

Comment: Why not? Does it work?

Comment: sorry but I'm not really able, now i try it if it works

Comment: Yes it works, thanks. But I do knot know which dimension I have to give to xnew(:). Using dimension(4) of course it stops after the fourth step

Comment: You must know it, we do not know your rules.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers.